# How to exit Chrome full screen on a Win tablet

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard

I have a tablet with Win10 on it and it works.

When I open Chrome it opens. Now, I want to go to full screen mode (NOT just maximize). Usually, I would do this with "F11" on the keyboard but this key doesn't exist on the touch keyboard.

Now one way is to set it to full screen over the Chrome settings, but then how do I exit this mode?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify:  what do you mean when you ask *"...but then how do I exist this mode?"*

Comment: I can get Chrome into full screen from the Zoom line in the options, but I can't get it out again, since the options are not present in full screen.

Comment: I meant exit, not exist, sorry!

Comment: No worries, we all have typos occasionally!  When I am in full screen mode in Firefox, I can move my cursor back up to the top of the screen to see the address bar and/or options and click the `Full Screen` button again to exit out of that mode.

Comment: but when I'm on a tablet, I don't have a cursor, right ?

Comment: But when you touch/swipe/pen to the top of the full screen Firefox browser window, the address bar and the Options button appear again.

Comment: mb with firefox but not with chrome

Comment: If that's the case, Chrome users may be at a bit of a disadvantage in your particular scenario.  When I first saw your topic subject line, I thought that I could chime in and help... I didn't realize you were focusing strictly upon Chrome.  Hopefully someone else who is a Chrome guru can join the discussion with an ideal suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I figured it out!  I had the same problem on my surface pro 6.  You can use a stylus or pen to drag down or swipe down from the top of the browser and a gray X will appear (its a bit finicky, you have to swipe without holding or it will disappear).  But if you don't have a stylus, what I did was hold down on the top of the browser for 3 seconds and the X will appear which will exit full screen mode.  Not sure why its not more intuitive.

Comment: Oh I guess you can long press anywhere in the browser and it will right click which will give you the option to exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it very quickly on my little tab, I can get out from full-screen by right-clicking on a empty place (no text, no images) and then pressing "Exit full-screen".

This option doesn't exists on Chrome 51 or less (I got to let Chrome Update on my tab before write here).

Even normal computers with mouse and keyboard allow this exit mode.

Comment: Good call on changing the topic subject line of your question, and I am glad that someone else who actually *is* a Chrome user was able to help!

Comment: Except if the page is running a flash application in full screen mode, in which case a long click does not work. I still haven't found a way of exiting full screen in this mode, except for connecting an external keyboard.

Comment: You can use a workaround; Right click on flash, click on "Get Information about Adobe Flash Player xxx.xxx.xx" (Or something similar, I got another localization). Flash will open a new HTML tab, so now you can right-click again and press "Exit full-screen".

Comment: To right-click on a tablet, two finger tap on an empty space.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I am more of a Firefox person.  I know that Firefox affords you the opportunity to use a `Full Screen` button within Options, or you can customize the interface and place it next to the address bar.  As a result, you can toggle in and out of a full screen interface in that manner on a Windows tablet.

When I am in full screen mode in Firefox, I can move my cursor back up to the top of the screen to see the address bar and/or options and click the `Full Screen` button again to exit out of that mode.

I assume that Chrome has a similar capability.

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing, you can also exit chrome fullscreen by simply long-pressing; hold your finger anywhere on the screen, and an "x" will appear at the top.  This may not have been true when the other answers were posted, I'm not sure in which version this was first implemented.

preview:
[image]

Comment: yup i noticed that, too, it now works like that, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If somebody still interested I made extension for Chrome adding "float" transparent button for toggling fullscreen. I don't have chrome developer account (cause it's worth 5 USD hahaha evilcorp). So I released only on GitHub

https://github.com/inetkachev/TouchFullscreenToggleForChrome

[Appearing after every touch (not mouse click). Hiding fast and smooth. You even able to press controls under this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPcNl.jpg)